# how take image from webForm?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hi everyone I have a web form with html Helpers

I have something like that..

```
 <div class="editor-label">
                <%= Html.Label("Package Name") %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%= Html.TextBox("name") %>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%= Html.Label("Information") %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%= Html.TextBox("info") %>
            </div>
```

to save data I do this in my controller...

```
 public ActionResult AddNewEntry(FormCollection formValue)
    {
       ....
            lp.Add(new Package
           {
               Id = lp.Count,
               Name = formValue["name"],
               Description = formValue["info"]
           });
```

But i need put image in my web form,so I do this..

```
<%= Html.Label("Imagen:")%>
 <img id="Img1" src="<%= elem.Path %>" alt="Library Image" class="target-image" />
```

the question is, How I take the image id to save in my object.. something like html.Image to do this...

Image= formValue["image"]

any idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An image is not an input element. So the"value" is not in the form collection.

Since you already have the url of the image, you can download the image on the server. And store these bytes as the image. I think this is what you try to accomplish.